# shell script for replacing a string with incremented value

Tags: shell

I have an `.xml` file in which I have to search for "`<reviseddate>`" tag. It can be present multiple times in the file. If so I have to replace the "`<reviseddate>`" tag as "`<reviseddate1>`" I need an shell script for this

The sample of the text is as follows:

```
Manuscript received <receiveddate>June 7, 2005</receiveddate>; revised             
<reviseddate> February 4, 2006 </reviseddate>, <reviseddate> August 14, 2006 </reviseddate>,
and <reviseddate> October 7, 2006 </reviseddate>. This work was supported by the 
<supported><agency-name>California Department of Transportation through the California  
Center for Innovative Transportation and the California Partners for Advanced Highway 
and Transit Program</agency-name><grant-grp/></supported>. The contents of this paper 
reflect the views of the authors and do not necessarily indicate acceptance by the 
sponsors. The Associate Editor for this paper was M. M. Sokoloski.</affnote-para>
```

The output should be as follows

```
Manuscript received <receiveddate> June 7, 2005 <receiveddate>; revised             
<reviseddate1> February 4, 2006 </reviseddate1>, <reviseddate2> August 14, 2006 </reviseddate2>,        
and <reviseddate3> October 7, 2006 </reviseddate3>. This work was supported by the 
<supported><agency-name>California Department of Transportation through the California  
Center for Innovative Transportation and the California Partners for Advanced Highway 
and Transit Program</agency-name><grant-grp/></supported>. The contents of this paper 
reflect the views of the authors and do not necessarily indicate acceptance by the 
sponsors. The Associate Editor for this paper was M. M. Sokoloski.</affnote-para>
```

I've tried:

```
for i in $c do 
   sed -e "s/<reviseddate>/<reviseddate$i>/g" $path/$input_file > $path/input_new.xml
   cp $path/input_new.xml $path/$input_file 
   rm -f input_new.xml 
done
```

Comment: Please decode your question.

Comment: for i in $c
do
sed -e "s/<reviseddate>/<reviseddate$i>/g" $path/$input_file > $path/input_new.xml
cp $path/input_new.xml $path/$input_file
rm -f input_new.xml
done

Comment: Use an XML parser; they are available for many languages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a Perl script like this to do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i = 1;
while (<>)
{
    while (m%<reviseddate>([^<]+)</reviseddate>%)
    {
        s%<reviseddate>([^<]*)</reviseddate>%<reviseddate$i>$1</reviseddate$i>%;
        $i++;
    }
    print;
}
```

For each line, for each unnumbered `<reviseddate>` tag, replace the tag with the appropriately numbered tag.

Sample output:

```
Manuscript received <receiveddate>June 7, 2005</receiveddate>; revised             
<reviseddate1> February 4, 2006 </reviseddate1>, <reviseddate2> August 14, 2006 </reviseddate2>,
and <reviseddate3> October 7, 2006 </reviseddate3>. This work was supported by the 
<supported><agency-name>California Department of Transportation through the California  
Center for Innovative Transportation and the California Partners for Advanced Highway 
and Transit Program</agency-name><grant-grp/></supported>. The contents of this paper 
reflect the views of the authors and do not necessarily indicate acceptance by the 
sponsors. The Associate Editor for this paper was M. M. Sokoloski.</affnote-para>
```

You can adjust this to deal with alternative scenarios, such as the start tag on one line and end tag on the next.  Until you need that, there's no point in fussing about it.  Using regexes is a fine art.  You need to balance the immediate need against the resilience for all possible scenarios.

---

Since Perl is apparently not 'shell' (but `sed` is), you can arrange to process the file often enough to find all the entries and change them.

```
tmp=$(mktemp ./revise.XXXXXXXXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

i=1
while grep -s '<reviseddate>' filename
do
    sed "1,/<reviseddate>/ s%<reviseddate>\([^<]*\)</reviseddate>%<reviseddate$i>\1</reviseddate$i>%" filename > $tmp
    mv $tmp filename
    i=$(($i+1))
done

rm -f $tmp # Should be a no-op
trap 0
```

This iteratively updates the file.  The `1,/<reviseddata>` part ensures that only the first `<reviseddate>` tag is update (there is no `g` on the `s%%%` command, and that is crucial).  The trap code ensures the temporary file is not left around.

This worked on your sample data, giving the same output.  For small files, it is fine.  If you're managing multi-gigabyte files, Perl is better because it processes the file once.